# Joomla module ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, joomla, module, joomla3.0

I created a module for joomla 3 when I load my page JQuery not working It gives following error.

```
 ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
 var $K2 = jQuery.noConflict();
 k2.js?v.../gslab/ (line 9, col 4)
```

Another on

```
 ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined 
 jQuery(window).on('load', 
 function() { contact...enstack (line 35)
```

And

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
contact...enstack (line 647, col 2)
```

I searched a lot not able to solve this issue, as jQuery not working not able to use j Query Date-piker. JavaScript code is working.

Comment: `Your CDN-hosted jQuery might be blocked`, how have you liked jquery ?

Answer (score 2):

It is error occur due to fact that the jQuery is not loaded before K2. You can correct this error if the switch jQuery load in K2 parameters.

Go to Component - K2 - Parameters and choose jQuery at "jQuery library handling" selector.